# RBDMS sqlite3 Error in insert operation..rollback

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to insert multiple records in an RBDMS table but receive the error

```
Error in insert operation..rollback
```

Could anyone help me fix the problem? Below is the code for adding multiple records and creating the table itself

```
# Insert multiple records in table DAY_CARE

qry="insert into DAY_CARE (dayCareID, dayCareWebsite, dayCareAddress, dayCarePhone, dayCareBills, clientID, clientBookingID, staffHead) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
daycarelist=[('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 1, 1, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100 , 2, 2, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 3, 3, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 4, 4, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 5, 5, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 6, 6, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 7, 7, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 8, 8, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 9, 9, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('day care','www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 10, 10, 'Bob Smith')]


try:
        cur.executemany(qry, daycarelist)
        conn.commit()
        print ('Records inserted successfully..committed')
except:
        print ('Error in insert operation..rollback')
        conn.rollback()
```

Here is the successfully created DAY_CARE table.

```
# Day Care Table
qry='''

CREATE TABLE DAY_CARE (
        dayCareID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        dayCareWebsite TEXT (40),
        dayCareAddress TEXT (50),
        dayCarePhone INTEGER (11),
        dayCareBills INTEGER (6),
        clientID INTEGER (50),
        clientBookingID INTEGER (50),
        staffHead TEXT (50) 
        
 );

'''
try:
        cur.execute(qry)
        print ('Table created successfully')
except:
# If table already exists then use the SQLite console to connect to the database and then use the drop table command.
# .. Altenatively, use the SQLiteStudio GUI to delete table ECC_DEPARTMENT and execute this code block again.
        print ('Error in creating table')
```

Comment: 1) print the exception 2) what is the primary key of the table? 3) share the CREATE TABLE

Comment: I've just updated the post with the code used to create the table

Comment: dayCareID is the primary key used

Comment: dayCareID is an integer primary key, which means it is autoincrement. Why do you try to insert the value 'day care' for it?

Comment: you pass 'day care' (which is a string) as `dayCareID`. The table definition tells us that it should be a unique integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dayCareID` is an `integer primary key`, which means it is `autoincrement`.
You should not include it in the list of columns in the `INSERT` statement:

```
qry="insert into DAY_CARE (dayCareWebsite, dayCareAddress, dayCarePhone, dayCareBills, clientID, clientBookingID, staffHead) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
daycarelist=[('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 1, 1, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100 , 2, 2, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 3, 3, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 4, 4, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 5, 5, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 6, 6, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 7, 7, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 8, 8, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 9, 9, 'Bob Smith'),
           ('www.eddc.co.uk','Exeter Doggy Day Care, Stoker Rd, Exeter, EX4 4PY', 1392661000, 100, 10, 10, 'Bob Smith')]
```

Also, note that setting the length of a column like `INTEGER(50)` or `TEXT(50)` in the table's `CREATE` statement, does not mean that this will be the max length of the column. 
In fact SQLite ignores it.

Comment: I made a mistake! I meant to `dayCareID` as text instead of an integer. Where I've created the table I've changed `INTEGER` to `TEXT`. I'm still met with the same error message of `Error in insert operation..rollback`. Can the primary key be a text primary key?

Comment: @a1b2c3 If dayCareID is the PRIMARY KEY then it must be unique. You can't insert more than 1 rows with the same dayCareID.

Comment: would the easiest solution be to change the PRIMARY KEY to an `INTEGER`, then replace the text in my original code with unique `dayCareID` numbers?

Comment: @a1b2c3 If a column is defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` there is no need to supply any value for it. It will get values like 1, 2, 3 etc for each new row. Check my code. Of course if you want you can supply values but they must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

It is dangerous to silently *eat* the error message, because it could be informative.

When I reproduced (without catching the exception) I got: `sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch`

As SQLite is very tolerant with datatypes, it meant an error with the primary key. You declared it to be INTEGER. In SQLite, it is a special case where that integer key becomes the *internal* primary key for the table. It then **must** be an integer and **must** be unique. The means that you must either set it to an integer sequence:

```
for i,l in enumerate(daycarelist):
    l[0] = i
```

and use the current query, or just does not set it in the insert statement and let the database autoincrement it:

```
daycarelist = [l[1:] for l in daycarelist]
qry = "insert into DAY_CARE (dayCareWebsite, dayCareAddress, dayCarePhone," 
    "dayCareBills, clientID, clientBookingID, staffHead) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```